# Powershell test for free capacity on C:/

Tags: powershell

Hello I'm not advanced in Powershell. I try to test if drive C:/ capacity is less than 2 GB with this script:

```
$date = get-date
$computer = $env:computername
$minspace = 2 # minimal space in GB
$disk = ([wmi]"\\$computer\root\cimv2:Win32_logicalDisk.DeviceID='c:'")
$free = "{0:#.0}" -f ($disk.FreeSpace/1GB)
$used = "{0:#.0}" -f ($disk.Size/1GB)

if($free -lt $minspace){
     Write-Host "$free is less than $minspace"
}
```

But the result is wrong. 
16,8 is less than 2

the values are strings. But when I try to convert it into a Number I get 168 for `$free`

how to test if the diskspace is less than 2GB?

Comment: Once you do the string formatting (with -f), the data types are strings, not integers.  So you need to either do the mathematical comparison before the formatting or you need to convert the values back to some form of number for the comparison ([int]$free) after the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

The problem that you're running into is that you're comparing a string to an integer in your `if ($free -lt $minspace) {}`, in that comparison, $free is a string (because of the formatting you applied), and $minspace is an integer.

If you want to check for disk space under 2GB, then check for it with numbers:

```
if ($disk.FreeSpace -lt 2GB) {
    ## Do something when below 2GB limit
}
```

if you type out 2GB and hit enter at the PowerShell prompt, you'll see that PowerShell converts it to an integer:  `2147483648`

Use string formatting (with -f) if you want to make the numbers look more human-readable but leave them as numbers (int,float, etc.) if you want to do numerical comparisons.